# How to clear drawn shape of Azure Map

Tags: javascript, azure, dictionary

I'm trying to draw shapes on Azure Map by using drawing toolbar, but it doesn't  have remove icon in this toolbar.
I'm trying write javascript to remove selected shape, but it doesn't work, however work by clear all shapes.

This is a part of my js code to clear all shapes:

```js
var source = drawingManager.getSource();
source.clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#clearPolyGonSelection" ).on( "click", function(event) {
    drawingManager.setOptions({ mode: 'idle' });
    drawingManager.getSource().clear();
    });
});
```

With some HTML like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="clearPolyGonSelection">clear polygon</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope it works**: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0bf016aa-fd31-4dee-8946-5440afeef9d4/drawingtools-how-to-delete-shape-from-the-map-how-to-drawedit-circle-using-bing-8-api?forum=bingmapsajax

```
if(condition){
     
     shapeName = null;

    }
```

**Might be in Your case**

```
source = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the shape you want to remove and then

```
drawingManager.getSource().remove(shape);
```